# How to find what $b$ satisfies $b^{176} \equiv -1 \mod 353$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test

How do I find what $b$ satisfies $b^{176} \equiv -1 \mod 353$?

This all comes from the original problem of using Proth's Theorem to prove the primality of $353$. Using Wolfram Alpha, $3^{176} \equiv -1 \mod 353$ but I need to at least show why that’s the case, and I’m not sure what the easiest way to do that is.

Would I use the Jacobi symbol or something? Exponentiation ($2^{176} = 2^{128}\cdot 2^{32}\cdot 2^{16}\equiv 1$) seems like it would take forever, especially if I had to test several $b$ values

Comment: The question is to find *all* $b$ that satisfy $b^{176}$ modulo $p=353$? Or is it about finding only one such multiple generator?! And $3$ was suggested.

Comment: @dan_fulea Just 1 example. Proth's Theorem is concerned with the existence of such a $b$

Answer (score 1):

The computation with bare hands is not that difficult at all... The following computations are done modulo $p=353$, equal means equal in the ring $\Bbb Z/353$. We have $3p=3\cdot 353=1059$, so numbers near $1000$ are getting smaller modulo $p$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
3^{176}
&=3^2\cdot (3^6)^{29}=9\cdot 729^{29}=9\cdot(23)^{29}
\\
&=9\cdot 23\cdot(23^2)^{14}
=207\cdot 529^{14}
=207\cdot 176^{14}
=207\cdot (352/2)^{14}
\\
&=207\cdot(-1/2)^{14}
=207/(16\cdot 1024)
=207/(-16\cdot 35)
\\
&=-207/560=-207/207=-1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We have now a generator of the units in $\Bbb Z/p=\Bbb F_p$. The structure of this units group $(\Bbb F_p)^\times$ is the one of a cyclic group. The element $3$ is a generator, since $352=2^5\cdot 11$, and neither $3^{(p-1)/2}$, nor $3^{(p-1)/11}$ is one. All other generators are of the shape $3^k$ with $k$ relatively prime to the order of the units group.

Comment: I think groups and rings are covered in modern algebra (which I haven't taken, and isn't a prerequisite for my cryptology/number theory course). Your computation helps though, thank you